# .on() not working for mobile after AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile

I am building a mobile website that loads content via AJAX so I'm using .on() to bind the document. When the page first loads, the code is working fine and the roster (#roster) shows after someone clicks a game block (div.game_block_saturday). It's after the AJAX content loads that .on() stops working on mobile for me.

jQuery:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).find('#roster').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).find('#roster').hide();
    }
}, 'div.game_block_saturday');
```

HTML:

```
<div class="game_block_saturday">
    <div id="roster">
        <form><input type="submit" value="EXCLUDE ME" /></form>
    </div>
</div>
```

What can I use that will continue to work after the AJAX?

In addition, I would also like to add .not() to exclude any "clicks" on forms within div.game_block_saturday from triggering the event.

Comment: Do you have duplicate `#roster` IDs?

Comment: I discovered that it's detecting it on a click of any element inside .game_block_saturday, but not .game_block_saturday itself

Comment: so the above code is working but its only detecting it on elements inside the class

Comment: What's your goal? What is it that's not working as intended?

Comment: Since it works on the elements inside .game_block_saturday, I would like it to also detect a click on .game_block_saturday itself, where there is blank space. Right now it's only triggering when you click on any element inside .game_block_saturday.

Comment: It's working fine on desktop but not mobile... On desktop as soon as you hover into .game_block_saturday it triggers. I'm not using jquery mobile due to a conflict with other js

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to reproduce the issue ... are you able to create a jsfiddle demo?